# Query by a LONG column

Tags: sql, oracle11g

We have a big project install coming up, and I'm writing SQL scripts to do some of the installation verification.  Some of the views that  are being modified are only different in the query, not in the names or numbers of columns.

These are hard to verify because dba_views stores the query text in a LONG column.  Ordinarily, I would use a query like this:

```
select *
  from dba_views
 where name = 'LOCKED_DOCUMENTS_V'
   and instr(upper(text), 'TLP') > 0;
```

to see if the view contained a particular text string it's code, but that doesn't work on a long column.

The only thing I have come up with so far is that I can check the text_length from dba_views, but it would be better to check the actual query.

Any thoughts on how to do this in a SQL script, which will be executed in SQL*Plus?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: I think you are SOL (somewhat outta luck) on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I'd use DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL like the following:

```
select 
   dbms_lob.instr(clob_contents,'TLP')
from 
   (select 
        dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW','LOCKED_DOCUMENTS_V', 'SCHEMA') clob_contents 
    from 
        dual) get_clob
```

Which will get you the position - as long as it is > 0 you are happy it is there.

Comment: That looks like it might do the trick!  I'll verify more tomorrow, and approve your answer, if it does what I need.  Thanks!

Comment: I changed it a bit to eliminate the subselect, but it would have worked that way, too:

   select 
   dbms_lob.instr(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW','LOCKED_DOCUMENTS_V', 'SCHEMA'), 'TLP')
from dual;